# TreeView thansfer on check box state

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I have 2 TreeView's and the first is populated with items.

```
try {
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> treeRoot = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Root");
    treeRoot.setExpanded(true);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        item = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("item " + i);
        treeRoot.getChildren().add(item);
    }

    treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);
    treeView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String> forTreeView());
    treePane.add(treeView, 0, 1);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want to transfer the items which have the check boxes checked to my second tree. If the root item is checked, all the child items must be added to the second tree. The same goes for sub roots.

I tried something like this but it isn't working.

```
int length = treeView.getExpandedItemCount();

CheckBoxTreeItem<String> treeRoot = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("On the other side");
treeRoot.setExpanded(true);

try {
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        item = (CheckBoxTreeItem<String>) (treeView.getTreeItem(i));
        if (item.isSelected()) {
            treeRoot.getChildren().add(item);   
        }

    }
    treeView.setRoot(treeRoot);
    treePaneExecution.add(treeView, 0, 1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a listener with the `selectedProperty()` of the `CheckBoxTreeItem`s, and move them when the selected state changes. Here's a quick example. You'll need to figure out what to do when the user checks the tree root - the behavior you want isn't really clear to me (should the first tree be empty?) - but this should be enough to get you started.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBoxTreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MovingCheckedTreeItems extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> uncheckedTreeRoot = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Unchecked tree");
        uncheckedTreeRoot.setExpanded(true);
        TreeView<String> uncheckedTree = new TreeView<>(uncheckedTreeRoot);
        uncheckedTree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());

        CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkedTreeRoot = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Checked tree");
        checkedTreeRoot.setExpanded(true);
        TreeView<String> checkedTree = new TreeView<>(checkedTreeRoot);
        checkedTree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());

        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Item "+(i+1));
            item.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
                item.getParent().getChildren().remove(item);
                if (isNowSelected) {
                    // add to checkedTree, will take all sub-nodes with it...
                    checkedTreeRoot.getChildren().add(item);
                } else {
                    // add to uncheckedTree
                    uncheckedTreeRoot.getChildren().add(item);
                }
            });
            uncheckedTreeRoot.getChildren().add(item);
        }

        HBox root = new HBox(5, uncheckedTree, checkedTree);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already used a different logic to get it working properly. Appreciate it though :)